# Showing a nested collection of intervals is unique

Tags: analysis

> Let $I_n = [a_n, b_n]\forall n \in\mathbb N$ be a nested collection of intervals. Suppose that $\inf\lbrace b_n − a_n \vert n \in\mathbb N\rbrace = 0$. Show that $$\xi\in\bigcap_{n = 1}^\infty I_n$$ is unique.

What is a nested collection of intervals? What can I use to start answering this problem?

Comment: Try [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=nested+collection+of+intervals&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS775US775&oq=nested+collection+of+intervals&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.4409j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Answer (score 1):

A nested collection would be one where $I_m \subseteq I_n$ if $m>n$ in your case. (The other inclusion order would be precluded by the fact that $|b_n - a_n| \rightarrow 0$.)

This condition implies that ${a_n}$ is an increasing sequence, bounded by any of the $b_n$, and ${b_n}$ is a decreasing sequence bounded below by any of the $a_n$. As monotonic bounded sequences have unique limits, both converge. Let $a_n \rightarrow \xi$ by definition. Then $b_n \rightarrow \xi$ as well, otherwise the limit would have to be higher (since $b_n \geq a_n$), and if it is different, say $l\neq \xi$, then the positive difference between the two limits, $|l-\xi| \leq |b_n-a_n|, \forall n$, would be a positive lower bound on the set $\{b_n - a_n|n \in \mathbb N \}$, which is not allowed.

$\xi$ is in all intervals because $a_n \leq \xi \leq b_n$, so it also belongs to the countable intersection. Moreover, any other element $\xi'$ in the intersection would be some distance away from $\xi$, and would be below all $b_n$ and above all $a_n$. Therefore $|\xi' -\xi|$ would be again a positive lower bound of $\{b_n - a_n|n \in \mathbb N \}$, so not possible.

Therefore $\xi$ is the unique element of the intersection.